# Is this the right way to run C codes in Atom?

Tags: c, atom-editor

I use a Windows machine and that's why I can't use script packages to compile my C codes.

I use [gpp compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler) package to compile my  C codes. It compiles my C codes and gives me the output right there in Atom. But, it doesn't create an executable file.

I want to know if there is any other way to compile the C code and get an executable file as well.

[Here's how I compile my C codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9511.png)

Comment: If it compiles and runs your code it creates an executable to do so.

Comment: There are many other ways to compile C and C++ programs. Visual Studio, Qt, using a makefile, etc.

Comment: You can also use sublime text integrated with your own build script.

Comment: @coderredoc I use Sublime Text too. It is one of my favorite editor. Well it compiles C codes and create exe file. But I've to open the folder where my code is to run the exe file. It doesn't run right there automatically. Sometimes it's annoying!!

Comment: @AbhijeetSaha.: I can help you with sublime text...but for that you need either change the question so that I can help you.

Comment: @Retired Ninja It compiles the code and give you the output right there but don't create an exe file.

Comment: It absolutely does create an executable.  Go look in your temp folder. Sort by date descending.  It's right in the options where it stores the file. IS your question about that, or asking to find a tool which is off-topic?

Comment: @RetiredNinja See there's no exe file here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VBIhjcT254aDd3ZHJ1dzh1LXc/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @coderredoc I will post another question regarding my this Sublime Text problem. Thanks!!

Comment: I must be imagining things... http://imgur.com/a/x6vBc

Comment: You can use Dev-C++ or Code::Blocks IDE, both are good for C and C++

Comment: @akshayk07 Thanks!! But this is not the answer of my question. And I use this two as and I know they're good.

Comment: You should not be coding and driving, especially high-performance sports cars:(

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that gpp_compiler *does* create an executable binary, but you might not know where it is.

My understanding is that the compiled binary is stored is some Windows temporary directory. I believe this behaviour can be configured in the Atom editor, and it can be saved to the location of the .c file instead.

https://github.com/kriscross07/atom-gpp-compiler/issues/66

Comment: Yes, You're right. It is here-C:\Users\abhi\AppData\Local\Temp. I found that.

Answer (score -2):

Use Keil UVision

for donwload https://www.keil.com/download/product/

for batter option for make executable and deployed hex file

Comment: Keil is a compiler for microcontrollers. Turbo C++ builds 16-bit executables for DOS systems. Neither one of these is appropriate for what the OP is asking for.